# RequireJS in Pentaho

Tags: javascript, requirejs, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

Without disabling RequireJS  how can I use Click Action for drill down using popup component in Pentaho? I enabled RequireJS and used the following code but its not working.

```
function f(e){
   var color = this.pvMark.fillStyle();
   dashboard.fireChange('product', e.vars.category.value);
   dashboard.fireChange('param3_color',color.color);
   render_PopUpComp.popup($(this.event.target));
}
```

Can anybody help me to do drill down by enabling RequireJS?

Answer (score 0):

use this.dashboard.fireChange instead.

Read this, it answers all the other questions about changes due to requireJS.